# How to using namespace in protocol-buffers with C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol buffer and want to make .cs file using Protobuf-net.

So, I prepared test1.proto and test2.proto files as following.

```
message Test1 {
    required string test = 1;
}

import "test1.proto";

message Test2 {
    required Test1 test = 1;
}
```

After that, test1 and test2.cs file was generated as following.

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated by a tool.
    //
    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    //     the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Generated from: test1.proto
namespace test1
{
  [global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Test1")]
  public partial class Test1 : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
  {
    public Test1() {}

    private string _test;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name=@"test", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public string test
    {
      get { return _test; }
      set { _test = value; }
    }
    private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
      { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
  }

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Generated from: test2.proto
// Note: requires additional types generated from: test1.proto
namespace test2
{
  [global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Test2")]
  public partial class Test2 : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
  {
    public Test2() {}

    private Test1 _test;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name=@"test", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public Test1 test
    {
      get { return _test; }
      set { _test = value; }
    }
    private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
      { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
  }

}
```

But, there is not "using test1" statement.
If I want to add using statement, is adding using statement manually only way?

Please teach me, thank you.

---

Thank you, Mr.Mark.
I use Protobuf-net.
And test1.cs code is as following.

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated by a tool.
    //
    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    //     the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Generated from: test1.proto
namespace test1
{
  [global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Test1")]
  public partial class Test1 : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
  {
    public Test1() {}

    private string _test;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name=@"test", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public string test
    {
      get { return _test; }
      set { _test = value; }
    }
    private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
      { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
  }

}
```

Comment: which tools are you using? Protobuf-net? Protobuf-csharp-port? And which namespace is Test1 generating in? Note: you mean "using directive", not " using statement"